# How do I add notifications to notifiy the user firebase tableview has been updated?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is for Swift4 and iOS 11.3

how do I add notifications to tableview when firebase updates the tableview

Comment: More information is needed for this question. What platform is this for? In general, you need to use a listener on one of the libraries and listen for changes in the route you care about, and the websocket will push the changes to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the listener section called `Listen for value events` of the realtime database documentation for swift. This will show you how to set up listeners that trigger when data has changed in specific sections of the database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write